# MySQL Bulk Insert taking long time

Tags: python, mysql, bulkinsert

I'm using python, using MySQL connector. I'm having nearly 67 Million (14GB) entries in a table. When I do a bulk insert of 2K data each time, it is taking very long to insert.

```
Inserted 2000 rows in 23 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 25 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 29 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 28 Seconds
```

For another table (having less data), insertion speed is fine(2-4 seconds).

---

After using the transaction:

```
Inserted 2000 rows in 21 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 20 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 20 Seconds
Inserted 2000 rows in 18 Seconds
```

How can I improve the speed?

---

I'm using AWS RDS, Aurora MySQL version 5.7.12 (db.t3.medium) having CPU usage 4% to 8%. My objective is to insert around 50K data into a table. This table is currently having nearly 67 Million (14GB) data already. Data must need to be inserted ASAP. This almost real-time data is very important for the client. The table is having 18 columns:
id(PK auto-increment), customer, serial_number, batch, data, and some others.
Indexes are on (customer,serial_number) - To make the combination unique, batch - For searching, data(unique). All are by default BTREE indexed.
This insertion should need to take less than 1 minute for 50K. But currently taking around 15 minutes. I've tried inserting on an empty table. It is inserting 50K data just in 5-7 seconds. As you increase the number of entries in the table, the insertion process time is increasing.

Is upgrading MySQL version is going to speed-up the insertion process anyhow?
Is it the last option to split or partitioning the table?
I cannot consolidate the data because each data is important, specially the last 2 years of data.
Please help.

My table schema is already having some default values in 8 columns and these data are never going to update later because real-time data is very important for us.
There are not many Read/Write operations are going on. Almost 2 or in some cases 3 selects per second as per RDS monitor shows.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on MySQL, but here are few strategies you can try

- Partitioning the table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html
- Archive older data into separate tables if feasible. Smaller the index memory footprint, the writes will be faster
- Give a bigger machine so that InnoDB has more memory and processing power

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with the UPDATE command - some of the delay may be attributable to Python's intrinsic speed issues, but most is likely due to mySQL and general server latencies.

I've gone "serverless" using SQLite (local db, everything in "core") and it's improved performance.

Comment: Currently serverless is not an option for us right now. And can't use SQLite because we are using MySQL functionalities which SQLite does not provide.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your goal is there are several options you might consider.  More information ultimately is useful.

If you are simply looking to free up availability you may consider using `INSERT LOW PRIORITY`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

What type of database engine are you using?

What indexes do you have on the table?  Unique indexes?

Is it possible to insert the rows with default values and run updates later asynchronously?

Are there a lot of write/read operations on that table happening at the same time?

Comment: Added in the question above.

Comment: It is taking around 1m 30s to insert 2K entries. Using transaction, 1m 24s. using CSV file and shell command to insert into remote database took 1m20 s. All I have done testing 4 to 5 times. These times are the average time of only database insertion of these tests not the python script execution time and all.

Comment: Should I migrate this table only in the ELasticSearch database?

Comment: I believe adding another database such as Elastic Search would be another much larger question.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your my.cnf ( or my.ini for Windows )

```
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # to expedite reducing innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty ASAP
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # to expedite insert capacity per second
```

see dba.stackexchange.com Question 196715 Rolando's suggestion # 2, please.